# Ошибка при подключении sockets.io (nestjs)

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

При подключении библиотеки sockets.io возникает ошибка в файле main.ts

[image: Скриншот ошибки1]

Выше видно и способ подключения.

**Код main.ts**

```
import {
  utilities as nestWinstonModuleUtilities,
  WinstonModule,
} from 'nest-winston';
import * as swStats from 'swagger-stats';
import * as winston from 'winston';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import AllExceptionsFilter from './exceptions-filters/all-exceptions.filter';
import BadRequestExceptionsFilter from './exceptions-filters/bad-request-exceptions.filter';
import * as Transport from 'winston-transport';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ConfigParam } from './enums/config-params.enum';
import { IoAdapter } from "@nestjs/platform-socket.io";



async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  const transports: Transport[] = [];

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    transports.push(
      new winston.transports.Console({
        format: winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.timestamp(),
          winston.format.ms(),
          winston.format.json()
        ),
        level: 'debug'
      })
    );
  } else {
    transports.push(
      new winston.transports.Console({
        format: winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.timestamp(),
          winston.format.ms(),
          nestWinstonModuleUtilities.format.nestLike()
        ),
        level: 'debug'
      })
    );
  }

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
    logger: WinstonModule.createLogger({
      transports,
    }),
  });

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('API')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document);

  app.useGlobalFilters(
    new AllExceptionsFilter(),
    new BadRequestExceptionsFilter()
  );

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })
  );
    const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');



  
    app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));

 
  app.use(swStats.getMiddleware({ swaggerSpec: document }));
  await app.listen(3000);
  
}


 // app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app))
    // const redisIoAdapter = new RedisIoAdapter(app);
  // await redisIoAdapter.connectToRedis();
  
  // app.useWebSocketAdapter(redisIoAdapter);

bootstrap();
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ControllersModule } from './controllers/controllers.module';
import { LoggerMiddleware } from './core/logging/logger.middleware';
import { DatabaseModule } from '@boilerplate/data';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import * as path from 'path';
import { IApiConfigParams } from './interfaces/api-config-params';
// import { EventEmitterModule } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
import { SocketModule } from './socket/socket.module';
import { ScheduleModule } from '@nestjs/schedule';

const serveStatic = process.env.NX_SERVE_STATIC === 'true';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true}),
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
            rootPath: serveStatic ? path.resolve(process.env.NX_SERVE_STATIC_PATH || 'client') : null,
        }),
        DatabaseModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: (configService: ConfigService<IApiConfigParams>) => ({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get('NX_DATABASE_HOST'),
                port: +configService.get('NX_DATABASE_PORT'),
                username: configService.get('NX_DATABASE_USERNAME'),
                password: configService.get('NX_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
                database: configService.get('NX_DATABASE_NAME'),
                logging: configService.get('NX_DATABASE_ENABLE_LOGGING') === 'true',
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService]
        }),
    ServicesModule,
    ControllersModule,
    SocketModule,
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(LoggerMiddleware)
        .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "api",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/bull": "^0.6.1",
        "@nestjs/common": "^8.2.5",
        "@nestjs/config": "^1.1.6",
        "@nestjs/core": "^8.2.5",
        "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
        "@nestjs/passport": "^8.1.0",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.2.5",
        "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "8.2.6",
        "@nestjs/schedule": "^2.1.0",
        "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.2.2",
        "@nestjs/swagger": "^5.1.5",
        "@nestjs/terminus": "^8.0.3",
        "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
        "@nestjs/websockets": "8.2.6",
        "@socket.io/redis-adapter": "7.1.0",
        "@types/cron": "^2.0.0",
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "bull": "^4.8.5",
        "nest-winston": "^1.6.2",
        "passport": "^0.5.2",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "pg": "^8.7.1",
        "prom-client": "^14.0.1",
        "redis": "4",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
        "socket.io": "4.5.0",
        "supertest": "^6.2.1",
        "swagger-stats": "^0.99.2",
        "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.41",
        "umzug": "^3.0.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "winston": "^3.4.0",
        "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5",
        "ws": "7.4.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.5",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^8.2.5",
        "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34"
    }
}
```

**socket.module**

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SocketGateway } from './socket.gateway';
import { ServicesModule } from "../services/services.module";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";

@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => ServicesModule), 
        ConfigModule
    ],
    providers: [SocketGateway],
    exports: [SocketGateway],
})
export class SocketModule {}
```

В чем может быть проблема? Скорее всего где то что то не так с версиями, или что то где то не экспортировал, хотя все проверенно очень плотно...

Код ошибки

```
(alias) new IoAdapter<any, any, any>(appOrHttpServer?: any): IoAdapter
import IoAdapter

Argument of type 'IoAdapter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebSocketAdapter<any, any, any>'.
  Types of property 'bindMessageHandlers' are incompatible.
    Types of parameters 'transform' and 'transform' are incompatible.
      Call signature return types 'Observable<any>' and 'Observable<any>' are incompatible.
        The types of 'operator.call' are incompatible between these types.
          Type '(subscriber: import("//node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("/home//path//node_modules/rxjs/internal/types").TeardownLogic' is not assignable to type '(subscriber: import("/home//path//node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/Subscriber").Subscriber<any>, source: any) => import("/home//path//node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types").TeardownLogic'.
            Types of parameters 'subscriber' and 'subscriber' are incompatible.
              Type 'Subscriber<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscriber<any>': syncErrorValue, syncErrorThrown, syncErrorThrowable, _unsubscribeAndRecycle, and 2 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если перенести зависимости на верхний уровень то все работает как надо.

(Пояснение: пакеты связанные с работой сокетов были только на бэкенде и на фронте, но в проекте есть еще отдельный файл, общий, с зависимостями, при установки туда - все заработало!)